# Modify text of specific CSV column with regex

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-7.2

Note: The full script is at the bottom of the question.

Let's assume I have the following CSV file (`data.csv`). It's a simple file with 2 columns: a name and a path of the corresponding person's folder in drive D.

```
name,path
A,D:\folder/A
B,D:\folder/B
C,D:\folder/C
D,D:\folder/D
E,D:\folder/E
```

I would like to change "/" to "" using the replace operator or method in PowerShell.

I begin by importing the CSV file:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path "misc/data.csv"
Write-Output $data

name path
---- ----
A    D:\folder/A
B    D:\folder/B
C    D:\folder/C
D    D:\folder/D
E    D:\folder/E
```

Then I use `ForEach-Object` to perform the desired operation of the `path` property like so:

```
$data | ForEach-Object {
    $_.path -replace "/", "\"
} | Write-Output
```

What I obtain is unfortunately an array of the modified values:

```
D:\folder\A
D:\folder\B
D:\folder\C
D:\folder\D
D:\folder\E
```

After looking at a few examples on the internet, I also tried this:

```
$data | ForEach-Object {
    $_.path -replace "/", "\"
    $_
} | Write-Output
```

The result I got was definitely unexpected for me:

```
name path
---- ----
A    D:\folder/A
D:\folder\B
B    D:\folder/B
D:\folder\C
C    D:\folder/C
D:\folder\D
D    D:\folder/D
D:\folder\E
E    D:\folder/E
```

Would you please advise? Thank you in advance.

Full script:

```
# Import CSV file

$data = Import-Csv -Path "misc/data.csv"
Write-Output $data

# Method 1

$data | ForEach-Object {
    $_.path -replace "/", "\"
} | Write-Output

# Method 2

$data | ForEach-Object {
    $_.path -replace "/", "\"
    $_
} | Write-Output
```

Comment: You just need to assign the modified value to the property.`$_.path = $_.path -replace ‘/‘,’\’`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My appreciation goes to @Doug Maurer who pointed out that the modified values need to be assigned back to the `path` property. The solution is therefore:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path "misc/data.csv"

$data | ForEach-Object {
    $_.path = $_.path -replace "/", "\"
    $_
}

name path
---- ----
A    D:\folder\A
B    D:\folder\B
C    D:\folder\C
D    D:\folder\D
E    D:\folder\E
```